# Sudomy doesn't see api keys

Tags: api, github, penetration-testing, penetration-tools, opentest

After installation Sudomy i add my API's to "sudomy_api_dist" file. But sudomy still doesn't see api keys.

While I wait for Sudomy to see the API keys and scan accordingly, it continues to scan without looking at other search engines as if I did not specify the api keys.

Answer (score 0):

I solve my problem. When try to scan with sudomy sudomy need api file "sudomy.api" but latest version of sudomy it gives you file name "sudomy.api.dist" so just change the file name to "sudomy.api" thats all.